# R: Convert a single banded rasterLayer with a colour table to a 3-band RGB rasterStack

Tags: r, crop, raster, geotiff, rgdal

Similar to the question raised in [R: Crop GeoTiff Raster using packages "rgdal" and "raster"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907825/r-crop-geotiff-raster-using-packages-rgdal-and-raster) I am trying to crop a map from the Swiss Federal Office of Topography with the packages "rgdal" and "raster" while preserving the original color table. For a single banded *.tif file the cropped image looses the color table information and, thus, is not displayed properly (the resulting image is almost black).

The input file can be downloaded [here](http://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/internet/swisstopo/de/home/products/maps/national/digital/national/pk_25.parsys.89625.downloadList.82162.DownloadFile.tmp/pk25komblzw.zip) and should be extracted in the folder "C:/files". This is the code:

```
## install.packages("rgdal")
## install.packages("raster")
library("rgdal")
library("raster")
input <- "C:/files/PK25_KOMB_20L_2004_1_1.tif"
output <- "C:/files/cropped.tif"
r <- raster(input)
ex  <- extent(c(600500, 601500, 196500, 197500))
cropped <- crop(r, ex)
writeRaster(cropped, output, format="GTiff", datatype='INT1U', overwrite=TRUE)
```

The solution presented in the before mentioned [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907825/r-crop-geotiff-raster-using-packages-rgdal-and-raster) only worked for a 3-band *.tif but not for a 1-band *.tif (such as the example file).

A solution that should work is to convert the single banded rasterLayer that includes a color table into a 3-band RGB rasterStack (as outlined in a comment in the before mentioned [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907825/r-crop-geotiff-raster-using-packages-rgdal-and-raster)) which apparently conserves the color table.

However, I do not know how to do convert a single band *.tif to a 3-band RGB rasterStack while preserving the color table. Does anyone know how this conversion can be done or does anyone have a better idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gdalUtils::gdalwarp` for this:

```
library(raster)
library(gdalUtils)
```

**Downloading the data:**

```
download.file(file.path('http://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/internet/swisstopo/de',
                        'home/products/maps/national/digital/national',
                        'pk_25.parsys.89625.downloadList.82162.DownloadFile.tmp',
                        'pk25komblzw.zip'), f <- tempfile())
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())
```

**Cropping with `gdalwarp`:**

```
cropped <- gdalwarp(
  file.path(tempdir(), 'PK25_KOMB_20L_2004_1_1.tif'), 
  'cropped.tif', te=c(600500, 196500, 601500, 197500), output_Raster = TRUE)
```

Note that the extent must be given as `c(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`, which is different to the order used for `raster::extent`.

**Confirming that it worked:**

```
plot(raster('cropped.tif'))
```

[image]